# SQL - Separating a merge field into separate fields based on delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table with an nvarchar(max) column including a merged text like below:

```
ID  MyString
61  Team:Finance,Accounting,HR,Country:Global,
62  Country:Germany,
63  Team:Legal,
64  Team:Finance,Accounting,Country:Global,External:Tenants,Partners,
65  External:Vendors,
```

What I need is to create another table for each item having the Team, Country and External values separated into 3 different columns.

```
Id   Team                      Country   External
61   Finance,Accounting,HR     Global    NULL
62   NULL                      Germany   NULL
63   Legal                     NULL      NULL
64   Finance,Accounting        Global    Tenants,Partners
65   NULL                      NULL      Vendors
```

What is the most efficient way to do it? I'm trying to use STRING_SPLIT but couldn't manage it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not completely normalising your design?

Comment: This is not my design, not allowed to change it.

Comment: Honestly, that data is a mess. SQL Server's string manipulation abilities is poor at best, so it is ill suited to trying to (partially) normalise the data. I would strongly suggest you fix the design from the ground up; you have de-normalised data with denormalised data in it (as you have comma separated values within those command separated values). The fact that the "column" delimiter is the same as the row value delimiter only compounds the problem. Parsing this data within SQL Server will be awful for performance, and messy.

Comment: If you have fixed output columns than you can do this with string manipulation but it require considerable effort.  However, STRING_SPLIT itself is not very useful for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Data resembles JSON, so we'll compose a proper JSON via few `REPLACE()` function calls.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, tokens) VALUES
(61, 'Team:Finance,Accounting,HR,Country:Global,'),
(62, 'Country:Germany,'),
(63, 'Team:Legal,'),
(64, 'Team:Finance,Accounting,Country:Global,External:Tenants,Partners,'),
(65, 'External:Vendors,');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('{"' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(',' FROM tokens), ':', '": "')
    ,',Country',  '", "Country')
    ,',External', '", "External') + '"}')
WITH
(
   Team         VARCHAR(100)    '$.Team',
   Country      VARCHAR(100)    '$.Country',
   [External]   VARCHAR(100)    '$.External'
) AS u;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------------------+
| ID |                              tokens                               |         Team          | Country |     External     |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------------------+
| 61 | Team:Finance,Accounting,HR,Country:Global,                        | Finance,Accounting,HR | Global  | NULL             |
| 62 | Country:Germany,                                                  | NULL                  | Germany | NULL             |
| 63 | Team:Legal,                                                       | Legal                 | NULL    | NULL             |
| 64 | Team:Finance,Accounting,Country:Global,External:Tenants,Partners, | Finance,Accounting    | Global  | Tenants,Partners |
| 65 | External:Vendors,                                                 | NULL                  | NULL    | Vendors          |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------------------+
```

Comment: This is much simpler than the path I went down,

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let me repeat my comments here. SQL Server is the *last* place you should be doing this; it's string manipulation is poor and you have a severely denormalised design, with denormalised data containing denormalised data. Fixing your design to a normalised approach must be a priority, as leaving your data in this state is only going to make things harder the further you go down this rabbit hole.

One method you could use to achieve this, however, would be with a JSON splitter and some restring aggregation, but this is real ugly. The choice of having the "column" and "row" delimiter to *both* be a comma (`,`) makes this a complete mess, and I am *not* going to explain what it's doing because you just should not be doing this.

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(61,'Team:Finance,Accounting,HR,Country:Global,'),
                (62,'Country:Germany,'),
                (63,'Team:Legal,'),
                (64,'Team:Finance,Accounting,Country:Global,External:Tenants,Partners,'),
                (65,'External:Vendors,'))V(ID,MyString)),
PartiallyNormal AS(
    SELECT YT.ID,
           CONVERT(int,LEAD(OJC.[Key],1,OJC.[Key]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY OJC.[Key], OJV.[Key])) AS ColumnNo,
           OJV.[value],
           CONVERT(int,OJC.[key]) AS [key]
    FROM YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(YT.MyString,':','","'),'"]')) OJC
         CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(OJC.[value],',','","'),'"]')) OJV),
WithNames AS(
    SELECT ID,
           ColumnNo,
           [value],
           [key],
           FIRST_VALUE(PN.[Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ColumnNo ORDER BY [Key]) AS ColumnName
    FROM PartiallyNormal PN)
SELECT ID,
       TRIM(',' FROM STRING_AGG(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'Team' THEN NULLIF([value],'''') END,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [key])) AS Team, --TRIM because I've not taken the time to work out why there are sometimes a trailing comma
       TRIM(',' FROM STRING_AGG(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'Country' THEN NULLIF([value],'''') END,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [key])) AS Country,
       TRIM(',' FROM STRING_AGG(CASE ColumnName WHEN 'External' THEN NULLIF([value],'''') END,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [key])) AS [External]
FROM WithNames WN
WHERE [value] <> [ColumnName]
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b09ef6f0c0adfee34602d3594fba7122)

Answer (score 0):

`STRING_SPLIT` in SQL Server 2017 doesn't tell us the order of the items in the list, so it can't be used here.
Only SQL Server 2022 would add a parameter to `STRING_SPLIT` that would tell the order of the items.

Until that version of SQL Server the most efficient method would likely be the CLR. Write your parser in C# and call your function using CLR.

Comment: There are other methods of splitting a string, other than `STRING_SPLIT`. Both a Tally splitter and a JSON splitter can retain and provide ordinal positions. The problem isn't *just* the ordinal positions though. A CLR function would work, but fixing the data to start with, and storing is normalised, is still by far, a much better (and performant) option.

Comment: @Larnu, well, at least with positions of each element it is possible to rebuilt the structure. Without positions it can't be done. Since the question was "What is the most efficient way to do it?" - a classic procedural language like C# is likely to be the most efficient method to parse the strings. Hence CLR.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

- splitting the string using the `STRING_SPLIT` function on the colon
- extracting consecutive strings using the `LAG` function
- removing the string identifiers (`Team`, `Country` and `External`)
- aggregating on the `ID` to remove NULL values

Here's the query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID,
           LAG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS prev_value,
           value
    FROM tab
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(MyString, ':')
)
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN prev_value LIKE 'Team' 
                THEN REPLACE(value, ',Country', '') END) AS [Team],
       MAX(CASE WHEN prev_value LIKE '%Country' 
                THEN LEFT(value, LEN(value)-1)      END) AS [Country],
       MAX(CASE WHEN prev_value LIKE '%External' 
                THEN LEFT(value, LEN(value)-1)      END) AS [External]
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f39251299cd33f4042198925d43cdc6d).